# Is possible on easy way to program in c++/lua in unity?

Tags: c++, lua, unity-game-engine

I want to learn Unity but C# is not my first choice. Is possible to program in c++/lua in unity ?
I want to escape from marmalade to unity or shiva.

Comment: have you thought about learning Unreal Engine 4?

Answer (score 1):

I will start by saying that C# is my favorite language and although I sometimes wish Unity could be fully programmed in C++ (especially when I need something that C++ would give) I do think C# lets you do almost everything you need but just a bit slower than C++.

You can make plugins with C++ but that is it.

Any particular reason why you want to do C++? Also if you know C++ you already know C#.

Comment: I am familiar with C#,I was working on ASP.NET on previous job, it is just I am more familiar with C++ and I prefer compiled languages (except for some scripts to use Lua),no other reason

Comment: I completely understand. I wish there was a work around for this.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. Except for plugin development.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/68109-Unity-and-C

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12809/can-i-use-c-as-a-scripting-lanques-for-unity.html